# understanding return type in swift autocomplete

Tags: swift

Can someone tell me why some method in swift code sense have "!" after the datatype. I am guessing it's an optional but now i am confused as to why not use "?" instead of this. i know that ! is used to  do forced unwrapping. please advice
Regard
jake

Comment: if you know ! is for force unwrap then what more you need?

Answer (score 2):

It is because using ! means that the method/variable/etc. **HAS** to return/have a **non-nil** value. Using ? means that it can be **nil**.

Sometimes methods **NEED** to return non-nil values. So that's why you force unwrap them. It's about safety.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. now i get it